# "Unfortunately, Google Play Store has stopped."

Tags: google-play-store

**Android 5.1.1**

Whenever I open Play Store, I recieve the message "Unfortunately, Google Play Store has stopped.". I can't seem to make it go away, I've tried restarting my tablet and clearing cache and data of Play Store.

Disabling and uninstalling Google+ doesn't solve it.

Comment: Have you seen our [google-play-store tag-wiki](/tags/google-play-store/info) – which interestingly linkes to a question titled [Unfortunately Google Play Store has stopped](/q/145311/16575)? The solution proposed there is almost the same as in Nikhil's answer below, just differently phrased.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that tag. Posts around here not helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Use the Aurora Store!

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, clearing the Google Play Store App cache may restore functionality. It's a very simple and quick fix that might help! :)

Answer (score 0):

We chose Download manager and cleared cache and data. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to application manager and go to Google play store and select u install  updates

Answer (score 0):

Download ApkPure apk from [HERE](https://apkpure.com/apkpure/com.apkpure.aegon/download).. Install it and update google play services from it..

HOPE IT HELPS...